# For Loop ignored while running an async function (Discord Bot using the Python API)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot that checks whether a certain key is in my database or not. All of the keys are listed in the first column of my CSV file. The value row[2] cointains a boolean parameter that tells the user whether the key is already activated or not. My problem is that the second for loop is being completely ignored. Instead of running the for loop, it directly tries to run `await client.send_message(message.author, status)` that obviously throws the following exception

> Local variable 'status' referenced before assignment

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    elif message.content.startswith("!activate"):
        with open('database.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
            content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            key_list = []
            for row in content:
                key_list.append(row[0])
            key = message.content.split(" ")[1]
            try:

                if key in key_list:

                    for row in content:
                        print(row[0])
                        if row[0] == key:
                            print(row[2])
                            status = row[2]
                    await client.send_message(message.author, status)
                else:
                    await client.send_message(message.author, "Your key was not found in our database. Make sure you use the proper format: ```!activate KEY```")  
            except Exception as E:
                print(E)
                await client.send_message(message.author, "Your key was not found in our database. Make sure you use the proper format: ```!activate KEY```")
````

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: The very first line of code in the function is an `elif`, which is an error.  Please fix the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this condition in your code:

```
if row[0] == key:
    print(row[2])
    status = row[2]
```

`status` is not defined anywhere else, so if `row[0]` is not equal to `key`, `status` is undefined.

What should `status` be in that case?

Comment: I don't think that's correct. The "await client.send_message(message.author, status)" is under the if condition as well. So if that gets run, it means that the if condition is True.

Comment: As posted, the `await` statement is **not** under the `row[0] == key` condition.

Comment: Yeah you are right, the indentation is wrong. But the point is, not even the print(row[0]) gets run.

Comment: If the indentation is wrong, _fix it_ so we can see the actual code you're running.

Comment: print(row[0]) is right above the if condition, so it should get run regardless of the outcome of if row[0] == key

Comment: Also, it wouldn't make sense. I just checked that "if key in key_list" is true, so there has to be at least one of the row[0]'s that is equal to key

Comment: You already consumed all the rows with the `for row in content` loop near the top.  There are no rows left, so the second `for row in content` loop never executes, not even once.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! How am I supposed to fix this? Should i close the csv file and open it back up?

Comment: You could do that.  Or in the first loop you could save the `row[2]` values in a local list, just as you do with the `row[0]` values, and then refer to that list instead of reading the file again.

Comment: Yup the second option worked like a charm. Thanks again John, marking your answer as correct!